# Why does this javascript async loop exit

Tags: javascript, debugging, asynchronous, firefox, async-await

I've used this pattern to update a webpage using js:

```
//global 
let noRefresh = true;
// ws is a webSocket object

async function UpdateLoop(ws){
  const delay = seconds => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000))
      while(noRefresh==true){
        await delay(10)
        await RequestChanges(ws)
      }

  await RefreshConnection(ws)
  UpdateLoop(ws);
}
```

This has been working fine. However, some other code is I think causing this loop to exit (or pause indefinitely). This happens when I run an "on click" function.

Presently I'm struggling to work out how to debug this. I've tried using console.log to check that it is not stuck in one of the awaited functions and stepped through the code to see what could be causing it, using the firefox debug tools.

**How do I track what is causing the browser to exit an async loop like the one above?** What is the best debugging approach here?

Comment: The only thing i know of that would stop that loop would be for `noRefresh` to change value or some uncaught error, but the former would show the error in the console. Where exactly did you put the console log calls,eg in between the await calls or in the promise chains, and what where the results?

Comment: @PatrickEvans Many thanks for the comment, in the end I realised that I was clearing all Timeouts (see answer).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was brute force clearing all timers in a 'mouseup' function (intended for timers set in click-hold functions), this also cleared the timeout in my loop.

I resolved by adding a global `timerID` var...

```
//global 
let noRefresh = true;
let timerID = ''
// ws is a webSocket object

async function UpdateLoop(ws){
  const delay = seconds => new Promise(resolve => timerID = setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000))
      while(noRefresh==true){
        await delay(10)
        await RequestChanges(ws)
      }

  await RefreshConnection(ws)
  UpdateLoop(ws);
}


$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    let id = window.setTimeout(function() {}, 0);
    while (id--) {
       if (id!=timerID){window.clearTimeout(id);}
    }
}
```